# useRootNavigator is not working with Navigator 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-getx

why useRootNavigator is not working with Navigator 2.0?

I tried to use useRootNavigator with dialog and with OpenContainer (from animations package)
But the URL is not changing

it's works with normal Navigator but it's not with Navigator 2.0

for example (I using Navigator 2.0 by GetX):

```
import 'package:animations/animations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
 
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Nav2',
      color: Colors.red,
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: '/',
          page: () => GetRouterOutlet.builder(
            builder: (context, delegate, currentRoute) {
              return GetRouterOutlet(initialRoute: HomeScreen.route);
            },
          ),
          participatesInRootNavigator: true,
          preventDuplicates: true,
          children: [
            GetPage(
              name: HomeScreen.route,
              page: () => HomeScreen(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
 
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static String route = '/Home';
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        // color: Colors.grey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            OpenContainer(
              useRootNavigator: true,
              routeSettings: RouteSettings(name: '/page2'),
              closedBuilder: (context, action) {
                return TextButton(
                  onPressed: action,
                  child: Text('OpenContainer test'),
                );
              },
              openBuilder: (context, action) {
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text('OpenContainer'),
                  ),
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text('look at the URL'),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                  useRootNavigator: true,
                  routeSettings: RouteSettings(name: '/dialog'),
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AboutDialog(
                      applicationName: 'look at the URL',
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                child: Text('Dialog test'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> dependencies:
>
> flutter:
>
> ```
> sdk: flutter
> ```
>
> animations: ^2.0.1 # https://pub.dev/packages/animations
>
> get: ^4.3.8 # https://pub.dev/packages/get

or can set the URL manually in navigator 2.0?